# Sum and Product combined infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

I am trying to solve a math puzzle asked in a puzzle competition.
The first part of the puzzle for me was to find an infinite sequence which is;

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{7}{6^1}+\frac{28}{6^2}+\frac{84}{6^3}+\frac{210}{6^4}+\frac{462}{6^5}+.......... 
\end{eqnarray*}

The result of this summation will be the "expected value" of a series of events.

Since the sequence is getting smaller and smaller towards zero, it should have a valid sum.

The sequence is not an "arithmetic series" because it does not have "common difference".

It is not a "geometric series" because it does not have "common ratio".

It is not an "arithmetico geometric series" because it does not have any combination of common ratio and common difference.

The only relation I found between the elements of sequence is this;

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{7}{6}+\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\frac{8}{2}\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{7}{6}\frac{8}{2}\frac{1}{6}\right)\frac{9}{3}\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{7}{6}\frac{8}{2}\frac{1}{6}\frac{9}{3}\frac{1}{6}\right)\frac{10}{4}\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{7}{6}\frac{8}{2}\frac{1}{6}\frac{9}{3}\frac{1}{6}\frac{10}{4}\frac{1}{6}\right)\frac{11}{5}\frac{1}{6}+.............
\end{eqnarray*}

So the notation of the relation between the elements of this infinite sequence is;

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pi_{j=0}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{j+7}{j+1}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Then, the summation of all the elements is;

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Pi_{j=0}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{j+7}{j+1}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Here I am done :)

I am not an expert mathematician, but a puzzle lover. I am not familiar with advanced mathematic and related notations. Because of the puzzle I am working on, I make deep dive to sequences and series concept. I don 't want the solution, I just need a clue to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.. Regards..

Comment: I am voting to close as there has been minimal to no effort put forward in this question. @borny, please show your work and where you are stuck.

Comment: I think defining the terms of the series from the given example is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac16\frac{j+7}{j+1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{6^k}\binom{k+6}{k}\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac16\right)^k\binom{-7}{k}\\
%&=\left(\frac65\right)^7-1\\[9pt]
%&=\frac{201811}{78125}
\end{align}
$$
The last sum can be evaluated using the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Comment: Than you very much robjohn. I have got the result.

Comment: Did you get the result from this hint and the Generalized Binomial Theorem, or somewhere else? What was the answer you got?

Comment: Yes, I get the result from your hint and Generalized Binomial Theorem. Thanks again. Result of the summation part is ; (1)/[(1-1/6)]^7=6^7/5^7=3,5831808
But this is not the complete answer. I get the answer by combining this with the rest of the solution. I don 't want to share the complete answer and the puzzle itself for the sake of the competition. If you give me a private adress I can share the puzzle with you. Competition is a long running marathon, You may want to attend :)

Comment: Was the downvote because there is something wrong? I left the last bit since this was [tag:contest-math].